# Javascript : setInterval in a while?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, setinterval, increment

Could you tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
while(buttonPressed) {

 setInterval(function () {

    food = food + farms + (farmers/2);
    updateFood();


  }, 1000);

}
```

I have a food value that increments automatically, faster or not depending on a few factors ( farms, farmers ).
It was working well without the loop but for a reason this function has to be executed only after I pressed on this button, and this is my problem.

I checked on the console, and the var buttonPressed by default false, changes to true after I pressed on the button, so it should work :/ I need your help :D

Thank you guys for replying :)

Comment: should your code run when the page loads or only when the button is pressed?

Comment: do you need to run it indefinitely or just once?

Comment: I need it to start only when I pressed on the button, then it runs indefinitely. But when my page load it shouldnt run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an infinite loop that (as quickly as it can) repeatedly starts intervals that function a function.

It sounds like you actually want a single interval that gets cleared when the variable changes. i.e. something like:

```
  var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (!buttonPressed ) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        return;
    }
    food = food + farms + (farmers/2);
    updateFood();
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: This works unless `updateFood()` *can* take longer than 1000ms to execute (or is an async operation). Better to use `setTimeout()` and call the function recursively.